# mpm_prefork:error AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting

Tags: php, magento, amazon-ec2, apache2, ubuntu-14.04

I have a simple magento website on a small AWS Ubuntu server and a small RDS, with only me visiting it. Every 3-5 minutes, apache crashes with this error:

`[mpm_prefork:error] [pid 7390] AH00161:server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting`

Right when it crashes, I have about 900M free memory of 2G. I checked the access logs and there are no other IP addresses but me. In the mpm_prefork.conf file, the default value for MaxRequestWorkers was 0; changed it to 150 and that has had no effect.

I have set up over a dozen Magento websites on AWS instances, and even more wordpress websites and I have never run into this issue. Does anyone have any good ideas why apache2 would do this right out of the box? This AWS instance is only a few days old.

Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Apache/2.4.7
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17

UPDATE: I've started a new t2.small EC2 instance, with only me visiting (confirmed in access.log) and copied the website over. It still points to the same RDS that hasn't changed. I'm getting the exact same error still! Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, thats what I meant above when I said "MaxConnectionsPerChild"; I'll edit it. So I raised the MaxRequestWorkers from 0 to 150 but it still crashes, and its only me visiting the site. I've had similar configurations that can handle several hundred visitors a day and I've never seen this error before.

Answer (score 1):

So after much digging, it turned out I WAS being DDOS. I had only checked the apache error.log file and only saw my IP address, but using netstat I found I was being hit with 300+ requests for whatever the time interval netsat reports on. Its off topic and I don't really understand the difference between what netstat and the apache error log is.

Comment: Well, I gave you your first +1. This post is what put me on the right track. I was under a DOS, but did not know it yet. I posted my findings here. http://serverfault.com/questions/667914/underused-apache-server-raise-maxrequestworkers-reached-memory-leak/800126#800126

Comment: If you a running a single small server, it was probably just a DOS attack rather than a DDOS attack. A single computer can produce a lot of data, or requests, and then it to a server. A distributed network isn't needed to take down one server.